# SSL Certificate Expired Exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am running an already developed project, It's occurring SSL Certificate Expired Exception, and It is not building the project, Gradle build not running.
It was working properly before yesterday.
The error is

```
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:97)
    ... 204 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    ... 219 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
    ... 219 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Jul 09 00:13:44 IST 2021
```

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a problem with your app — Fabric's SSL certificate for their Maven artifact repository expired. Until they fix it, you will not be able to load artifacts from `https://maven.fabric.io/public`.

Comment: Thank you. So can I deploy this app by removing the fabric library?

Comment: @romil: That will get you past this specific error. I do not know whether your app can work without the library, though.

Comment: @romil: The certificate problem seems to be fixed now!

Answer (score -2):

Error: Not After: 'date'
or
Error: java.security.cert.certificateexpiredexception
If you Experience this error in android studio simply invalidate caches and restart..,
on menu bar choose File->Invalidate Cache->Invalidate Cache and restart